# Using the Wildfly webserver, how do I run two .ear files, so that each one is selected based on url domain name?

Tags: server, jboss, wildfly-10

I'm running Wilfly version 10, that has two domain names pointed at the server.
We'll call them applicationone.com and applicationtwo.com.
I have deployed two different .ear files.
We'll call them applicationone.ear and applicationtwo.ear

I have my standalone.xml configured with two hosts:

```
<server name="default-server">
<ajp-listener name="ajp" socket-binding="ajp" max-parameters="5000"/>
<https-listener name="default" socket-binding="https" max-post-size="2147483648" max-parameters="5000" security-realm="ssl-realm" verify-client="REQUESTED" enabled-cipher-suites="TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384" enabled-protocols="TLSv1.2"/>
<host name="default-host" alias="www.applicationone.com" default-web-module="applicationone.ear">
    <filter-ref name="cache-control-header"/>
    <filter-ref name="pragma-header"/>
    <filter-ref name="expires-header"/>
    <filter-ref name="x-content-type-options-header"/>
    <filter-ref name="x-frame-options-header"/>
    <filter-ref name="x-xss-protection-header"/>
    <filter-ref name="strict-transport-security"/>
    <filter-ref name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin"/>
    <filter-ref name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers"/>
</host>
<host name="applicationtwo" alias="www.applicationtwo.com" default-web-module="applicationtwo.ear">
    <filter-ref name="cache-control-header"/>
    <filter-ref name="pragma-header"/>
    <filter-ref name="expires-header"/>
    <filter-ref name="x-content-type-options-header"/>
    <filter-ref name="x-frame-options-header"/>
    <filter-ref name="x-xss-protection-header"/>
    <filter-ref name="strict-transport-security"/>
    <filter-ref name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin"/>
    <filter-ref name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers"/>
</host>
```

But, I continue to get errors, either with the .ear deployment or with the host configuration. This is an early version of Wildfly and we're not able to update it right now.

Comment: What kind of errors are you getting?

Comment: Nothing specific. When I said error I think it was misleading. Either it fails to deploy both projects, or it will only display one in both urls, or one display its project while the other shows a 404

Comment: Those 2 ear applications have the same name on the pom.xml? If it is the case, you need to change 1 of them in the pom.xml

Comment: @ikora they have different names